# what is the solution, I cant install oracle XE 21c showing this error

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46pA.png)it keeps telling me to install the environment variables and I'm just getting started installing the Oracle XE 21c.[oracle xe environment variables error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrO80.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you already installed Oracle database (or some other products?) whose installation script created those environment variables. Find them and **remove** them from your computer.